# Facebook iOS SDK giving 'The page you requested was not found' after login

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook

I have successfully created an iOS app that uses FB Connect to log in the user to an application. To do this I set up a Fake App on Facebook. When I then tried to switch the details to the App my business client has setup on FB I started getting `The page you requested was not found` after login.

I've changed the App ID in my code and in my plist. I thought this should be enough, but obviously it is not working.

Is there anything that I'm missing here?

Comment: Hi Eric, have you worked around this problem?